# VC++ Dll Not Working On Windows XP Sp3 When Using C++ Builder

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++builder

I have created VC++ Dll in Visual Studio 2013.

```
extern "C"  int  __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl ConvertImageToText(char* dataPath, char* imageFilePath, char* captchaCode)
{
  // to do 
  return 0;
}
```

I'm using in Borland C++ Builder 6 like that.

```
  HMODULE dllHandle = LoadLibrary("Captcha.dll");
  int (__cdecl *ConvertImageToText)(char*,char*,char*);
  ConvertImageToText =(int (__cdecl *)(char*,char*,char*))GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "ConvertImageToText");
  if (ConvertImageToText != NULL )
  {
    ConvertImageToText("","","");
  }else
  {
   ShowMessage("ConvertImageToText pointer not found !");
  }
```

it's working well in win7/8/8.1.there isn't any problem.

But can't find pointer of ConvertImageToText on windows xp sp3.

I have changed VC++ Dll Project "Platform Toolset" as "Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)".nothing not changed.

I have checked Visual C++ Redistributable packages.All installed

Any sugguestions ?

Comment: Please can you tell us what happens. How do you obtain `dllHandle`. Is it non-NULL. Why didn't you call `GetLastError` as the documentation states?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have edited the questions. 
I will check getlasterror now.

Comment: I have checked returned
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx ERROR_SUCCESS :D

Comment: Can you try with SDK 7.1?

Comment: I will try your sugguestion thanks

Comment: You could readily have got your error checking code wrong. Why won't you show it? It really is the very most important thing to do, checking for errors. Please don't ever neglect error checking.

Comment: The most likely culprit is that either 1) `LoadLibrary()` is failing, which you are not checking for. Maybe the DLL has a dependency that is missing on XP; or 2) the function is not being exported as "ConvertImageToText" anymore when you recompiled the DLL for XP. In VC++, you have to use a `.DEF` file to remove decorations from exported names. Maybe the Win7+ version of the DLL is doing that but the XP version is not.

Comment: @David Heffernan You're right. I have checked.Dll not loading on xp.
dllHandle is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement proper error checking as described by the documentation.

1. Test the return value of `LoadLibrary`. A value of `NULL` indicates failure. If that is so, call `GetLastError` for extended error details. 
   E. Test the return value of `GetProcAddress`. A value of `NULL` indicates failure. If that is so, call `GetLastError` for extended error details.

Likely `LoadLibrary` is failing because your DLL is linked to a runtime that is not installed on the target machine, or because your DLL is linked to Win32 API functions that do not exist on XP.

If you cannot work it out from here you can use Dependency Walker for extra debugging. Use it in profile mode to debug the loader's attempt to load the DLL. That will reveal enough information to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed that redist release. it worked.

[image]